# Removing Windows 7 from dual boot, what would be the best method out of the following options

Tags: dual-boot

Was wondering how I should remove windows, using gparted or reinstalling ubuntu as a single os? I have downloaded very little in ubuntu, so re-installing it wouldn't be a problem. Would this be a suitbale option? or is  using gparted, then deleting GRUB a more suitbale option? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Ubuntu. Both reinstalling (and choosing 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu') as well as deleting the windows partition with GParted will do the trick. If you dont mind reinstalling I would go for that because it's easier.
I was however triggered by the last part of your comment:  .. then deleting GRUB..
Don't delete GRUB! You will still need to have GRUB to launch Ubuntu, even if you dont have windows anymore. It isn't only for dual booting scenario's. Just thought I would clear that up.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, and clearing up the issue about GRUB, glad I didn't do that. I'll probably just re-install it then. Thanks again.